# Calculate the velocity of a spinning ball and its deceleration

Tags: calculus, physics

I have a little different and interesting question. We had a dispute with my maths teacher after we've watched this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZAXGalYPhs (please watch after 2:30).

Long story short - is it possible to predict where the ball in a game of roulette will fall if you know when exactly the ball passes a certain number (for example 0). If you know the first 5-10 time intervals, is it possible to calculate the deceleration and the speed of the ball and get that information.